# Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent: when LOOPED, but display correctly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to load images from server in a loop, it might have no image or max 3 images. Loading the image through URLRequest.

Not very sure how to correctly put this into a loop, it is giving me error 2044 twice then it display the image correctly. Thanks for your time and help!

```
for (var j:int = 5; j < somedata.length; j++) 
            {
                var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
                var image:Bitmap;
                var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.rentaid.info/rent/"+somedata[j]);
                myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
                myLoader.load(url);




                function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void {
                image = new Bitmap(e.target.content.bitmapData);

                var mw:Number = bf.width*2;
                var mh:Number = bf.height*1.2;   
                    image.y = bf4.y+25;
      /* if you set width and height image same with the stage use this */
                image.width = mw;
                image.height = mh;
                addChild(image);

                }
            }
```

Edit:

```
for (var j:int = 5; j < somedata.length; j++) 
            {
                if(somedata[j]==! null){
                var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
                var image:Bitmap;
                var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.rentaid.info/rent/"+somedata[j]);
                myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
                myLoader.load(url);




                function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void {
                image = new Bitmap(e.target.content.bitmapData);

                var mw:Number = bf.width*2;
                var mh:Number = bf.height*1.2;   
                    image.y = bf4.y+25;
      /* if you set width and height image same with the stage use this */
                image.width = mw;
                image.height = mh;
                addChild(image);

                }
            }
            }
```

Comment: Seems like some files are not exist,  add `IO_Error` handler too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081749/actionscript-3-check-if-an-external-file-exists-and-if-so-unhide-a-movieclip

Comment: Yer that error only appear when i put that in a loop,  when i put somedata[5] it works but when i start a loop at 5 and put somedata[j], then it has that error twice, then display the image.

Comment: What's the length of `somedata`, and are there files for other data in there? Given your feedback, the length of `somedata` is 8, and the `somedata[6]` and `somedata[7]` contain unrelated info.

Comment: Hi Vesper, i just check the database, there was no other things in somedata[6] and somedata[7], in somedata[5] it is just "a.png" nothing else. If i place somedata[5] directly and replace somedata[j] and remove the loop. It works perfectly fine, but when i put in the loop, it gives me that error.

Comment: I believe i found out the reason, its because somedata[6] and somedata[7] is empty, but how would i do a loop that if somedata[j] is not null then carry on the loop, if [j] is empty then finish loop?

Comment: I tried to put a if statment inside the loop, there is no error but it doesnt add anything. I place what i tried in the edit above. I also tried if somedata[j] ==!undefined. Doesnt work either

Comment: Just use `if (somedata[j])`. And I don't know if `==!` is a valid operator, never tried it.. Always worked with `!==`..

Comment: Awsome Andrey, it works, THANKS!

Comment: I am just wondering, is there anyway to manipulate the child added within that loop, because i cant even removeChild or add that child to other class. That child is added, then when i try to do anything with that child from outside the loop, it says Parameter Child must be non null.....